# gray font compilation failure

Tags: metafont

while compiling the gray font using the default mode (ljfour), I get this message: "I can't write on file 'gray.log'...". The complete message is shown in the attached figure. In addition, no files such gray.tfm and gray.[number]gf were produced, which means that the compilation was failed. I tried to compile using the cx mode (with switching the input parameter of the gray.fm file into cx), but without success.
Informations about the environnement used:

1. Operating system: Windows 7 32-bit [version 6.1.7601]
2. MiKTeX [version 20.7 32-bit]
3. METAFONT [version 2.7182818]
4. DVI previewer: YAP [file version 4.0.0.0]
5. Display resolution: 600dpi
6. METAFONT mode: ljfour (HP Laser Jet 4 (600dpi))
7. compilation mode: ljfour

Any help would be deeply appreciated.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

MetaFont creates multiple files in the directory you are in when you run it. In your case, thi directory is the system directory where TeX is installed. By default you are not allowed to create files there (because it could interfere with what other people on your PC are doing), therefore MetaFont complains that it can't create it's files.

You can solve this by using another working directory: Instead of switching to the path under `C:\Program Files\...`, go to some directory which belongs to your user account and run the MetaFont command there. (Don't worry about MetaFont finding the input files, by default MetaFont should find it's input files in the MikTeX directory if they don't exists in your current directory.)

Comment: About the last sentence: in fact, until [about a month ago](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/672), Metafont on MikTeX did not find input files in the current directory, only system directories!